# Is it "élite" or "elite"?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, sustantivos, acentuación, deletreo

I have seen both ways of writing the word in texts:

> Esta transformación de la estructura básica de la sociedad repercutió en seguida sobre la constitución de la "**élite** política".
>
> [...] y el respeto hacia las instituciones sabiamente establecidas en el transcurso de los tiempos para mantener el prestigio de la **elite** que mueve el pulso de la vida [...].

Which is the proper one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Both are correct.

---

The word *élite* (or *elite*) is a loan word from French *élite*. It means:

> **[élite](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EXtXytb)**
>   Tb. **elite**.
>
> Del fr. *élite*.
>
> 1. f. Minoría selecta o rectora.

The trick is that the *é* in French does not mean that the first *e* is stressed, it only indicates the proper way of pronouncing it ([/e/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) vs [/ɛ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel)). So in French it is pronounced (roughly) as [elít].

You can [read this](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=elite) in the *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*:

> The French word *élite* [...] was adapted to Spanish as *elite* [elíte]; but the original word *élite* also circulated a certain time unchanged from French, so people who did not know French pronounced it the Spanish way: [élite]. Although this pronunciation goes against its etymology, it is today the most common way of writing this word [...]. Thus, the *élite* form and its pronunciation are also considered valid.

So in the end both ways ended up being accepted by the RAE, although the form *élite* was not accepted until very recently (2001 while *elite* was included in 1984).

This is the first match in [CORDE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/corde):

> *En Europa, donde las grandes masas de tropa están en columna y el campo de batalla abraza aldeas y villas diversas, las tropas de **élite** quedan en las reservas para acudir a donde la necesidad las requiera.*
>
> Domingo Faustino Sarmiento, "Facundo. Civilización y barbarie", 1845-1874 (Argentina).