# ¿Qué palabras provenientes del francés cogieron un acento en la "e" por su escritura francesa, sin que su pronunciación la tuviera?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, acentuación, deletreo, francés

En [Is it "élite" or "elite"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19384/1674) vimos que la palabra *élite* también puede escribirse *elite*. Esto es así porque viene del francés *élite*, que se escribe así pero se pronuncia [elít]. En algún momento de la historia, cuando se incorporó la palabra al castellano, alguien vio la escritura francesa e interpretó el acento.
Tal y como [comenta el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=elite): *la grafía francesa *élite*, que circuló como extranjerismo durante un tiempo, dio lugar a que muchas personas pronunciasen esta voz francesa interpretando la tilde a la manera española, es decir, como palabra esdrújula.*

El otro día me di cuenta que esto ocurre también con paté:

> [**paté**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=pat%C3%A9). Voz tomada del francés ***pâté***, ‘pasta untable hecha generalmente de hígado de cerdo o aves’: *«Adorna el paté con unas aceitunas rellenas cortadas por la mitad»* (Arguiñano Recetas [Esp. 1996]). Su plural es *patés* (→ [plural](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i), [1a](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i#1a)).

Si le pedimos a Google Translate que [nos lo pronuncie](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=es&text=p%C3%A2t%C3%A9), vemos que es algo así como [páte], que bien se podría haber traducido como "pasta" directamente. O eso, o "pate", pero se optó por *paté* seguramente por un argumento parecido al de *élite*.

Llevado por el descubrimiento de este caso, ¿qué os parece si recuperamos otros casos parecidos?

Buscando [en dirae.es por "del fr"](https://dirae.es/palabras/?search_type=&search_scope=&q=del%20fr) veo casos prometedores como [*cuché*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BY2aakc) (se pronunciaría [[cúshe](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=es&text=cuch%C3%A9)]) o incluso un caso diferente como [*echarpe*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EJvdWDy) (*chal*, que se pronuncia [[échagp](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=es&text=%C3%A9charpe)] por lo que la *e* final podría haberse omitido).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Foreword:** most linguists don't consider French to have lexical stress at all. It instead is analysed as having prosodic stress, where the final syllable in a *phrase* is stressed (or the penultimate one, if the final one is a schwa). Consider the following example:

> It was found that listeners whose native language was French performed significantly worse than Spanish listeners in reproducing the stress patterns... The explanation is that Spanish has lexically contrastive stress, as evidenced by the minimal pairs like tópo ("mole") and topó ("[he/she/it] met"), while in French, stress does not convey lexical information and there is no equivalent of stress minimal pairs as in Spanish.
>
> - [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)#Stress_"deafness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)#Stress_%22deafness%22)

This makes it difficult to consider how close/far a Spanish pronunciation of an originally French word is based purely on where the stress lies.

---

The RAE nominally only includes words which are pronounced 'as they are written', unless they appear in italics in their DLE entries, in which case they are considered unnativised foreign words with unpredictable pronunciations. If it contains multiple unitalicised orthographies (such as *élite* and *elite*), then the RAE's position is that these represent multiple common pronunciations in Spanish, and you 'should' use the spelling that corresponds with how you pronounce it (though this doesn't necessarily represent actual use e.g. [judo / yudo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/se-pronuncia-judo-con-la-j-espa%C3%B1ola-en-alguna-parte)).

There are many variant ways French words have been adopted in Spanish, I'll include a semi-complete list of ones containing é below (excluding many French inherited infinitive verbs, which in Spanish never have accents). Immediately below is a list of those whose Spanish pronunciation is not on the final syllable:

- hégira (*hégire*), anélido (*annélide*), canéfora (*canéphore*)
- intérlope (*interlope*), céntimo (*centime*), anécdota (*anecdote*)

And some words which gain an extra syllable:

- crepé (*crêpe*), peroné (*pérone*), [rulé](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WoySm5W) (*roule*), [giroflé/jiroflé](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JDXLS6Z) (*girofle*), [dragea/gragea](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EBNE3fO) (*dragée*)

---

### Appendix

**Words which gain accents absent in the French:**

- yeyé (*ye-ye*)
- cuplé (*couplet*), tupé (*toupet*), quinqué (*Quinquet*), cabriolé (*cabriolet*), parqué (*parquet*), bufé (*buffet*), carné (*carnet*), chalé (*chalet*), [croché](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BKi6mZh) (*crochet*), [buqué](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6IHqNmZ) (*bouquet*), cabaré (*cabaret*), corsé (*corset*), bidé (*bidet*), taqué (*taquet*), caché (*cachet*)
- sifué (*surfaix*), relé (*relais*), bisoñé (*besogneux*)
- [paspié](https://dle.rae.es/?id=S5IUXkD) (*passe-pied*), avampiés, marchapié, pitipié, avantrén (*avant-train*), terraplén (*terre-plein*)
- [yaqué/chaqué](https://dle.rae.es/?id=c9PPTWg) (*jaquette*), claqué (*claquette*), gotelé (*gouttelette*)
- harén (*harem*), satén (*satin*)
- neerlandés (*néerlandais*), inglés (*angleis*)
- entremés (*entremets*), exprés (*express*), kermés (*kermesse*), bauprés (*beaupré*)

#### Words which conserve the French accents:

- palmarés (*palmarès*)
- [rapé](https://dle.rae.es/?id=V92Yxkb), [vergé](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bdebUGB), [praliné](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TtdzK1J), plaqué, perlé, piqué, chiné, panaché, lamé, cliché, macramé, acné, comité, canapé, paté (*pâté*)
- [cuché](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BY2aakc) (*couché*), cupé (*coupé*), [moaré/muaré](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PRwm9Jj) (*moiré*), grancé (*garancé*), glasé (*glacé*), chimpancé (*chimpanzé*), virulé (*bas roulé*)
- suflé (*soufflé*), [consomé](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AQZsRBd) (*consommé*), capitoné (*capitonné*), fricasé (*fricassé*)
- melé (*mêlée*), puré (*purée*), cartoné (*cartonée*), bombé (*bombée*), palé (*palée*), matiné (*matinée*)
- varietés (*varieté*)

#### Words with double accents:

- [demodé](https://dle.rae.es/?id=C9ehPZB0) (*démodé*), bebé (*bébé*), ecarté (*écarté*)

Comment: ¡Nunca dejan de sorprenderme tus excelentes respuestas! Cojo palomitas y me la leo