# What are some words like "ícono" whose accentuation vary?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, ortografía, acentuación

The word "ícono" can be written as 'esdrújula' or 'llana'.

What are some other words whose accentuation can vary?

Comment: you mean, same meaning but different spellings? or similar spellings, different meaning?

Comment: There is a list of similar words at the end of this answer: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27435/18348

Comment: @IriaPoncelaBlanco - I think OP means same meaning, different spellings.

Comment: In some places they say fríjoles so frijol can also be fríjol

Comment: that sounds like a bad misspelling, fríjol, it should be frijol according to spelling rules

Comment: @IriaPoncelaBlanco http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fríjol

Comment: In Colombia they definitely say fríjoles!

Answer (score 4):

Since you seem to be only interested in knowing some words in the same situation as *icono*, here you have a couple of them:

- [elite](http://dle.rae.es/elite), élite <sup>1</sup>
- [bustrófedon](http://dle.rae.es/bustr%C3%B3fedon), bustrofedon, bustrofedón
- [período](https://dle.rae.es/per%C3%ADodo), periodo
- [video](https://dle.rae.es/video), vídeo <sup>2</sup>

---

1 <sub>See [Is it "élite" or "elite"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19384/1674)</sub>

2 <sub>See [video o vídeo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=video) in the *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*</sub>

Comment: What about that infamous méndigo/mendigo that got me so confused recently?

Comment: @aparente001 note that "méndigo" does not mean the same as "mendigo" so I have not included it.

Comment: Thanks. // I'm so confused about that pair.  I thought the meanings were related.  There's a lot of judgment in Mexico.  Well, at least what I've heard, is not so much against the person doing the begging, but there's a belief, I don't know if it's true, that there's a family member behind the scenes, sending the infirm person out to the sidewalk to beg, and pocketing the money.

Comment: Si buscas en Google "rae dpd dos acentuaciones, ambas válidas" encontrarás un montón: fútbol, Rávena, formica, páprika, Rumanía, pixel, _-scopia_, olimpiada, balano, bronquiolo, voleibol, chofer, bungaló, basquetbol, _-fito_, etc. Muchas son adaptaciones de otros idiomas.